# How to disable the single value from list in f:selectitems?

Tags: java, primefaces

```
   <p:selectOneMenu id="currency" value="#{element.selectedCurrency}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="--N/A--" itemValue="NA:-1"></f:selectItem>
    <f:selectItems value="#{returnBodyBean.selectedCurrency}"
                    var="currency"/>
    <p:ajax listener="#{returnBodyBean.onCurrencyChange(element)}"
    update="dataTypeConfigId,lovTypeId"></p:ajax>
  </p:selectOneMenu>
```

The List in f:selectItems contains 3 values. i want to disable the values in list based on selection of value in another drop down.
for eg:- if i change the value in other dropdown, I want to disable two values in the f:selectitems list.
Can you please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can't "disable" values in an html selection list, what you need to do is recreate the list that's displayed, minus the two values you want removed.
Set an update="currency" attribute on the other dropdown, then have the selectedCurrency method of your bean generate the list based on the value selected in that other dropdown.

Comment: Thank you. will check the way u suggested.

Answer (score 0):

How does your managed bean look like? Have you implemented `onCurrencyChange()`?

You could reload/reset the value list from dropdown #2 after you checked the selected item in dropdown #1 and update the second one.

Comment: How is this answer different than the one already given? Other than containing a question (which should be a comment)

Comment: @Kukeltje Actually, I am not able yet to comment on a question. I need more reputation... So I thought this would be the only way.

Comment: No, gaining enough reputation to comment is the right way by actually real answers that get accepted. Answers like this stand a chance of getting downvoted or flagged as not an answer which in turn results in even less reputation.